# webpack-dev-server is setting wrong path for root localhost:8080

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm real beginner in ReactJS. I need you help to set up webpack-dev-server for localhost:8080.
I'm following this [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtKh6tp44Ck&list=PLLnpHn493BHFfs3Uj5tvx17mXk4B4ws4p&index=9) to set it up, but I can't get success yet while in the tutorial its working. it sets root path as *../node_module/.bin* and listed me files in it. It should set root as "react-for-everyone".

See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbscG.png) to check file hierarchy, browser and command for the webpack-dev-server.

package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "react-for-everyone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies":{
      "babel-core": "^6.1.*",
      "babel-loader": "^6.2.*",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.*",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.*",
      "webpack": "^1.13.*",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.*"
  },
  "dependencies":{
      "react": "^15.3.*",
      "react-dom": "^15.3.*"
  }
}
```

webpack-config.js:

```
module.exports ={
//  entry:'./src/App.js',
    entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/App.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "react-for-everyone"),
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./react-for-everyone",
    },
    module:{

        loader:[{
            test: "/\.jsx?$/",
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel",
            query: {
                preset: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">This is an App.</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly check and let me know the issues where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: your youtube tutorial link is incorrect. Also you have a typo in `publichPath` correct that and see if it works

Comment: I have edited the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtKh6tp44Ck&list=PLLnpHn493BHFfs3Uj5tvx17mXk4B4ws4p&index=9) link, kindly check

Comment: Did you try and fix the typing mistake

Comment: No, its still displaying [this page](http://prntscr.com/ct7tg6). But if we put our index.html in this folder then it displays content in it, however .jsx and .js will not going to work with this **trick**, _its not a standard I guess._

Comment: Which folder you mean. Its already in your react-for-everyone folder right

Comment: No, I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtKh6tp44Ck&list=PLLnpHn493BHFfs3Uj5tvx17mXk4B4ws4p&index=9) so I write command in  this **G:\wamp\react-for-anyone/node_modules/.bin** directory like this **G:\wamp\react-for-anyone/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server**.

In case if you want I write command *G:\wamp\react-for-anyone* here I won't work either, see [screenshot](http://prnt.sc/ct7r0r)

Both cases, its not working

Comment: add `"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src"` in your scripts in package.json and then run you code from the react-for-everyone directory as `npm run dev`

Comment: `"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base"` works fine displaying index.html instead of adding `src` at the end of it.  However, new issue is now code of App.js is not rendering .... following [next tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3NhF71i2es&index=11&list=PLLnpHn493BHFfs3Uj5tvx17mXk4B4ws4p)  If you don't mind is there any latest tutorials that's works fine with updated REACTJS? Kindly let me know I have searched and tried many of them but anyone doesn't work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base"` in `scripts in package.json` and run your webpack form the `react-for-everyone` folder as `npm run dev`

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-for-everyone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies":{
      "babel-core": "^6.1.*",
      "babel-loader": "^6.2.*",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.*",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.*",
      "webpack": "^1.13.*",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.*"
  },
  "dependencies":{
      "react": "^15.3.*",
      "react-dom": "^15.3.*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Go with this tutorial series this is good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhkGQAoc7bc.

Answer (score 0):

You are running webpack-dev-server command within the ../node_module/.bin folder therefore webpack-dev-server will serve this folder. You have to be careful where to use this command because it it aware of the folder it was started from.

To solve your problem move to G:\wamp\react-for-anyone and run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` within this folder.

This should allow webpack-dev-server to find your index.html and serve it on http://localhost:8080.

Comment: Its not working either in this folder, _webpack-dev-server is not recognized as and internal or external command_. check the this [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/ct7r0r)

Comment: The actual programm 'webpack-dev-server' still sits in ./node_modules/.bin, thus you have to run the command ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server in your react-for-everyone folder.

There is  another options to make it work: Install webpack-dev-server globally (npm i -g webpack-dev-server). This allows you to run webpack-dev-server from any folder. See https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally

Comment: Thanks, you have given me new way to learn React...
Globally its not working, I'll explore it later...