# React component isn't rendered to index.html

Tags: reactjs

I'm really beginner in ReactJS. Component isn't rendering, I've wasted a lot of time to search that but unsuccessful.
I'm following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3NhF71i2es&list=PLLnpHn493BHFfs3Uj5tvx17mXk4B4ws4p&index=11) from this series. I've already configured webpack-dev-server from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912717/webpack-dev-server-is-setting-wrong-path-for-root-localhost8080).
Check the file hierarchy below, according to the tutorial.

[image]

Kindly let me know the problem.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>React</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';  
class AppFirst extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello ReactJs</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
var appElement = <AppFirst />;
Raect.render(appElement, document.getElementById("app"));
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "react-for-everyone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies":{
      "babel-core": "^6.1.*",
      "babel-loader": "^6.2.*",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.*",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.*",
      "webpack": "^1.13.*",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.*"
  },
  "dependencies":{
      "react": "^15.3.*",
      "react-dom": "^15.3.*"
  }
}
```

webpack-config.js

```
    module.exports ={
    entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/App.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "react-for-everyone"),
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./react-for-everyone",
    },
    module:{

        loaders:[{
            test: "/\.jsx?$/",
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel",
            query: {
                preset: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: `Raect` is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.render()` is no longer used with the current versions. React has split the library from 0.14 version. You need to use `ReactDOM.render()`  apart from the typo that you have in `React.render()`

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

```js
class AppFirst extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello ReactJs</h1>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    var appElement = <AppFirst />;
    ReactDOM.render(appElement, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In your webpack you have put quotes in `test: "/\.jsx?$/"` you shouldn't have them. `test: /\.jsx?$/`. It should be a regex and not a string

Other corrections you need to do.

1. Rename your webpack-config.js to webpack.config.js
2. In webpack loaders you need to define `presets` and not `preset`
3. Include path in your package.json with `npm install -S path` and webapck as `var path = require('path');`
4. Change your directory structure with `index.html` included in src
5. You final webpack looks like this

**webpack.config.js**

```
 var path = require('path');

 module.exports ={
    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    entry: [
    './App.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src",
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module:{

        loaders:[{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

6. Change your script in `package.json` to `"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src"`
7. Finally after doing `npm run dev` open `http://localhost:8080/index.html`

Comment: still not working by adding `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom;` and `ReactDOM.render`.
Kindly let me know where from you are importing `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; ` ?

Comment: First do npm install -S react-dom and then import it

Comment: `react-dom` is already installed and mentioned in **Dependencies**, still not working

Comment: which version of react and react-dom are you using. can you post your webpack and package.json

Comment: Is there ant problem `<script src="app.js"></script>` with it while my react code is in `App.js`, these are two different file, please check it.

Comment: There shoudn't be. Did you try removing quotes in your webpack test command and then see if your app.js actually contains anthing because its size turns out to be 0 kb so most likely your webpack is not converting you code because of the test command

Comment: When you do `npm run dev` what msg do you see.

Comment: See the updated answer, I have verified that it works on my system. You had a number of problem in you code. Not referring to the correct context was one of them.

Comment: 'react-dom' instead of 'react-dom/client' helps me, thank you!