# Using React.js on Codepen.io, Why is the custom tag not rendering?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, babeljs, codepen

A very beginner and dumb question maybe but still, everyone learns at first..

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="container">
```

**CSS(SCSS)**

```
$back:#1D1F20;
$font:'Open Sans',sans serif;
body{
  background-color:$back;
  padding:20px;
  h1{
    font-family:$font;
    color:white;
  }
  DisplayBox{
    font-family:$font;
    color:white;
  }
}
```

**JS (Babel)**

```
var DisplayBox=React.createClass({
  render:function(){
        return (
          <h1>Marked</h1>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<DisplayBox />,document.getElementById("container"));
```

My aim is to render the custom tag DisplayBox inside the #container but it is not rendering in codepen.io
[JS config in Codepen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVMvc.png)[CSS config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQAzJ.png)

Thank you for your help in advance :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React component isn't rendered to index.html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043522/react-component-isnt-rendered-to-index-html)

Comment: Since your are using 15.4.2 version of React, I suggest you to move to the ES6 way of creating React componets by extending React.Component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
React.render(<DisplayBox />,document.getElementById("container"));
```

Use

```
ReactDOM.render(<DisplayBox />,document.getElementById("container"));
```

Check the working [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNPQPQ?editors=0010)

Check the [difference between `React` and `ReactDOM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114350/react-vs-reactdom)